# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable for uuid value- Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, uuid

I am getting following error while retrieving the uuid value

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```py
import uuid

hash_val = uuid.uuid4().hex()

print(hash_val)
```

```py
#Error
hash_val = uuid.uuid4().hex()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Thank You

Comment: It's `.hex` and not `.hex()`